# Link Error During gRPC shared library build

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, grpc

When I try to build gRPC as a static library everything works fine. Nevertheless, I have link troubles when build it as a shared lib.

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "build shared libraries" ON)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        grpc
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
        GIT_TAG        v1.49.1)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(grpc)
```

```
protoc-3.21.6.0: error while loading shared libraries: libprotocd.so.32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This error occurs during execution script via `add_custom_command` inside the grpc

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error message is pretty clear:

```
protoc-3.21.6.0: error while loading shared libraries: libprotocd.so.32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To build the shared library of gRPC you also need the shared libraries for the protocol buffer compiler i.e. `protoc`. I would start by building the shared libraries of `protoc`.

If you are sure that you have them then I would check that CMake can correctly find them (by either checking if they are in the standard system paths or by appending the location of the .cmake file using `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`)

Hope it helps.